# Tomcat abnormal shutdown

Tags: tomcat6

I have tomcat 6 running perfectly all jsp files tested and working, but Tomcat get closed abnormally any time, i am not able to diagnose the cause.

Suggest how to diagnose.

Comment: Could you please add more detail to your question? Especially OS version and error messages / stacktraces from log files would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it is happening every time you log off and it is a Windows box you are logging off, add the -Xrs switch to your jvm startup parameters.  Windows logoff events are misinterpreted by the jvm as shutdown events and the jvm unloads.

If it is a unix host and you connect remotely with an ssh client, make sure that x11 port forwarding is disabled in your client.  It causes problems in jfreechart, which results in abnormal shutdowns, too.  If you do need x11 port forwarding enabled, modify your tomcat startup parameters with: unset DISPLAY.

If none of these apply, make sure your app isn't calling System.exit() anywhere.  That could do it, too.